# Check if text field is empty in flow builder

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, visual-flows

I have a requirement to override the default validation message shown in Flow-Builder for required form fields (text fields to be specific) that are left empty by the user.

I'm trying to achieve this by providing my own validation formula and then specifying the validation message.

According to the documentation, I should use `ISBLANK` to perform the check, but this is not working and I don't get any validation messages. Here's how this is setup for one of those text fields:

[image: Validation Setup]

I've also tried to check for this using LEN() and ISNULL() (Docs say ISNULL is not recommended any more though).

I'm not entirely sure why this doesn't work as intended. I haven't come across any links suggesting this might be a bug with the platform, so assuming I'm doing something very wrong here.

Comment: Did you try to use the API Name you specified on the screen field instead of using the variable which is set by the field?

Answer (score 2):

Having a similar requirement here are what I found out based on my own testing

If you do not check the Mandatory checkbox which blocks the user if there is no input in that field and try to replicate this rule using the validate input in flow then you will be stucked because:

- In flow the validation rule is called validate input
- If there is no input ***it would seem that*** the system will not
  check your validate input rule ==> No input = No need to check for
  validate input

Then what's left is to find a workaround:

- You could likely use some apex or custom component for flow (might
  seems a bit expensive for what we are trying to achieve but i'm
  saying it all)
- Work with what you have in standard but won't be pretty:
  You could assign a default value to your text field and make your validate input based on this default value
  **{!TextInput} != "Default Value"**

Of course this last workaround is not perfect because the user could just erase the default value to a blank value with no way of stopping him.

You could extend this idea of default value to validate the input of a user depending on your needs.

Hope this helps and save you guys some time until Salesforce make it happens.

Edit: I tried using api name as mentionned in previous answer but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

1. try using API name of the text field in the formula instead of a variable.
   Eg. ISBLANK(API NAME)
2. Place a display text below the input field and set it visibility when flag is true.

On click of next add a difference to check if the input field is blank. If yes, assign flag to true and connect it back to the screen to display validation.
Else, carry the rest of the process.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screen_validate.htm&type=5), "If the user leaves the field blank and the field is not required, the flow doesn’t validate."

Answer (score 0):

all this is another workaround it works for me at least.
My Blank fields should have been populated based only if another field was in a certain Status, so what I did was put in the visibility option to display the "blank" field only if my criteria were met (ie: Type=Order). I put my field required of course.